# prove the L’Hospitals rule without Cauchy's Mean Value Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

I am trying to prove the L’Hospitals rule in the following using **the mean value theorem of the differential calculus** instead of **Cauchy's Mean Value Theorem**(the generalized mean value theorem of differential calculus).

Consider two functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$, continuous on a closed interval $[a, b]$ of the X-axis, and differentiable on the interior of that interval. We assume that $g'(x)$ is positive and $f(a) = g(a) = 0$. The ordinary mean value theorem of differential calculus applied separately to $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ furnishes the expression:
$$\frac{f(x) - f(a)}{g\left( x \right) - g\left( a \right)}=\frac{f'(c_1)}{g^{'}\left( c_2 \right)}.$$
where $c_1$ and $c_2$ are suitable intermediate values in the open interval $(a, x)$. 
After taking limit on both sides and substituting $f(a) = g(a) = 0 $,  one got
$$\lim _{x\rightarrow a+}\frac{f(x) - f(a)}{g\left( x \right) - g\left( a \right)}=\lim _{x\rightarrow a+}\frac{f(x)}{g\left( x \right)}=\lim _{x\rightarrow a+}\frac{f'(c_1)}{g^{'}\left( c_2 \right)}$$
However, L’Hospital’s Rule needs $$\lim _{x\rightarrow a+}\frac{f(x)}{g\left( x \right)}=\lim _{x\rightarrow a+}\frac{f'(x)}{g^{'}\left( x \right)}$$
so I wonder whether $\lim _{x\rightarrow a+}\frac{f'(c_1)}{g^{'}\left( c_2 \right)}=\lim _{x\rightarrow a+}\frac{f'(x)}{g^{'}\left( x \right)}$ hold in this case ?

---

Some progress I have made in solving the problem :

1. For every x, there always exist $c_1$ and $c_2$ in (a, x), so one
   can denote  $c_1=m(x)$ and $c_2=n(x)$, then $$\lim _{x\rightarrow
   a+}\frac{f(x)}{g\left( x \right)}=\lim _{x\rightarrow
   a+}\frac{f'(c_1)}{g^{'}\left( c_2 \right)}=\lim _{x\rightarrow
   a+}\frac{f'(m(x))}{g^{'}\left( n(x) \right)}$$(As @Bernard pointed out in the comment - if there are several $c_1$s
   or  $c_2$s in $(a, x)$,  then I would choose any one of them, then  $c_1$ and $c_2$ are functions of $x$ .), so the problem
   becomes : whether $\lim _{x\rightarrow
   a+}\frac{f'(m(x))}{g^{'}\left( n(x) \right)}=\lim _{x\rightarrow
   a+}\frac{f'(x)}{g^{'}\left( x \right)}$ hold in this case ?
2. As $x$ approaches $a$, $c_1$ and $c_2$ also approach $a$ because it
   always lies between $a$ and $x$.

Comment: Writing $\lim _{x\rightarrow a+}\frac{f'(c_1)}{g^{'}\left( c_2 \right)}$ is meaningless because $c_1$ and $c_2$  are *not* functions of $x$.

Comment: @Bernard I think not. For every x, there always exist $c_1$ and $c_2$ in (a, x), so one can denote  $c_1=m(x)$ and $c_2=n(x)$. BTW, as $x$ approaches $a$, $c_1$ and $c_2$ also approaches $a$ because it always lies between $a$ and $x$.

Comment: And if there are  several $c_1$s or $c_2$s?

Comment: @Bernard Oh, I haven't considered that. If there are several $c_1$s or  $c_2$s,  then I may choose any one of them

Comment: With the axiom of choice? It raises some fundamental questions…

Comment: @Bernard No, I mean if there are several $c_1$s or $c_2$s  in (a, x), then I would choose any one of the  $c_1$s or $c_2$s with respect to $x$, so that  $c_1$ and $c_2$ are functions of $x$.

Comment: The problem is – how would you choose? Mathematically this can be impossible. Suppose there's an infinite number of $c_i$s…

Comment: I doubt if there is way to salvage your approach. If you are willing to use the ordinary mean value theorem then you should have no qualms about using one of its easy consequences the Cauchy Mean Value Theorem.

Comment: If one assumes that $g'(x) $ tends to a finite non-zero limit and $f'(x) $ tends to a finite/infinite limit as $x\to a^{+} $ then your process works because your $c_1,c_2$ both tend to $a^{+} $. But in other cases you are out of luck.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Thanks again :) I don't have any qualms on using the Cauchy Mean Value Theorem to prove the L’Hospitals rule, but just want to know if it is possible to use the ordinary mean value theorem to do the proof.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh  If I was right , one can only evaluate the limit of an indeterminate form  using the L’Hospitals rule provided the n-th derivative of g(x) tends to a finite limit and the n-th derivative of f′(x) tends to a finite/infinite limit as x→a, the condition is almost the same as you said my process works...

Comment: @ParamanandSingh ... If  $\lim _{x\rightarrow a+}\frac{f'(c_1)}{g^{'}\left( c_2 \right)}$ is another  0/0 indeterminate form, one can evaluate  $\lim _{x\rightarrow a+}\frac{f''(d_1)}{g^{''}\left( d_2 \right)}=\lim _{x\rightarrow a+}\frac{f'(c_1)}{g^{'}\left( c_2 \right)}$ or proceeded in a similar manner until the limit can be evaluated.

Comment: @Bernard What difficulty would arise if there's an infinite number of $c_i$s to choose ?

Comment: The problem is : *how do you choose?*. Limits are defined for `functions`. Which well-defined function do you have?

Answer (score 0):

Since we have the same restrictions of domain for $f, g$ we can say that without loss of generality that $c_1 = c_2$.

Fully the proof would be as follows:

If $x \in (a,b)$, then by the Mean Value Theorem applied to our given restrictions of $f,g$ to $[a, x]$, there exists some $\xi_x \in (a,x)$ with $$\frac{f'(\xi_x )}{g'(\xi_x )}=\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{g(x)-g(a)}=\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$$

Since $\xi_x \rightarrow a$ as $x\rightarrow a_+$ we have $$\lim_{x\rightarrow a_+} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\lim_{x\rightarrow a_+} \frac{f'(\xi_x)}{g'(\xi_x)}$$

Comment: Sorry, but Cauchy's Mean Value Theorem is the same as the generalized mean value theorem of differential calculus, I don't want to use it to prove here

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Cauchy's Mean Value Theorem; that is
$$\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{g(x)-g(a)}=\frac{f'(c)}{g'(c)}$$
for some $c$ such that $a<c<x$. Thus when $x\to a^+$, one has $\to a^+$. So
$$\lim _{x\rightarrow a+}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\lim _{x\rightarrow a+}\frac{f'(c)}{g'(c)}=\lim_{c\rightarrow a+}\frac{f'(c)}{g'(c)}=\lim _{x\rightarrow a+}\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}.$$

Comment: Sorry, but Cauchy's Mean Value Theorem is the same as the generalized mean value theorem of differential calculus, I don't want to use it to prove here